# Firebase high data bandwidth

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to save text in Firebase, and save it into Realtime database. Text is around 1300 symbols, so it's not too much. But when I try to load this text(Android, Java), Firebase data bandwidth is increase rapidly: 20kb, 50kb, 100kb,...500kb and I don't know why.

Does somebody know whats wrong?

Comment: It's difficult to say anything useful without seeing what you do. But in general, if you [enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel) you can see exactly what data the Firebase client sends and receives.